# In Flask/Jinja, how can you provide hooks for extensions/plugins to alter templates?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to add functionality similar to wordpress hooks in a flask application.

What I mean by that is that you could define extension points in your template where plugins could register callbacks to add/modify the output.

This is crazy, I know this is something I should not be doing, but I want to try anyway.

Basically, a hook would be called with something like that:

```
    {{do('before_title')}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{do('after_title')}}
```

Hooks could be registered with:

```
hooked = defaultdict(lambda: [])

def do(event, *args):
    return (cback(*args) for cback in hooked[event])

def add_action(event, cback):
    hooked[event].append(cback)

app.jinja_env.globals['do'] = do
```

And when registering the hook, the code would look like that:

```
def print_stuff():
    return 'some stuff to print'

add_action('before_title', print_stuff)
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to use the jinja environment to directly print the output, because, right now, if would have to loop in the templates, and it does not make for a fun api.

It would also be cool if I could register stuff like this:

```
def print_template(template):
    # some magically obtained object representing the jinja template or env
    template.include('before_title.html')

add_action('before_title', print_template)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was actually quite simple.

```
def include_template():
    return render_template('partials/before_title.html')

add_action('before_title', include_template)
```

And

```
def do(event, *args):
    return ''.join(cback(*args) for cback in hooked[event])
```